# Time Series for a large data set in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I'm very new to SQL, so far I've only used select statements and have little to no experience with loops or variables in SQL.

I've got a very large data set in SQL server; hourly observations for a year from 2230 different observation points (nodes). The table I'm working with looks like this:

```
TIMESTAMP                  NodeName  VALUE
2015-01-01 00:00:00.000    NODE 1    5
2015-01-01 00:00:00.000    NODE 2    10
2015-01-01 00:00:00.000    NODE 3    15
2015-01-01 01:00:00.000    NODE 1    6
2015-01-01 01:00:00.000    NODE 2    12
2015-01-01 01:00:00.000    NODE 3    5
```

I'm trying to find a way to build spread data (that is, NODE 1's value - Node 2's value for the same entry of TIMESTAMP) for all the nodes in the NodeName column. The order of the spread is not important to me, meaning NODE 1 - NODE 2 is the same as NODE 2 - NODE 1. I've built things using python to do this from a SQL dump, but was having issues with memory and disk space.

Ultimately I'd like to insert the results of this statement into a new table, with columns like:

```
TIMESTAMP                SPREADNAME          SPREADVALUE
2015-01-01 00:00:00.000  NODE 1 - NODE 2     -5
```

However, I'd be very happy just to get pointed in the right direction.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: So if you have 2230 nodes, you want (2230 * 2229 / 2) = 2485335 spreads for each timestamp?

Comment: I assume you mean 'datetime' instead of 'TIMESTAMP' (those are two very different data types)

Comment: re: Quassnoi; yes that is correct
re: pmbAustin- i just called the column TIMESTAMP, the entries are datetime. I didn't know there was a data type called TIMESTAMP

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  nn1.timestamp, nn1.nodeName, nn2.nodeName, nn1.value - nn2.value spread
FROM    nodes nn1
JOIN    nodes nn2
ON      nn2.timestamp = nn1.timestamp
        AND nn2.nodeName > nn1.nodeName
```

Please note that if that's a year's worth of hourly observations from 2230 nodes, you'll get about 22 billion records in your output resultset.

Create an index on `nodes (timestamp, nodeName)` if you want the query at least to start.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give that a try. Any chance I could get a quick explanation as to what's happening with your statement?

Comment: @dclair: for each row in your table it gets the rows with the same timestamp but greater nodeName (to remove pairs duplicates and self-matches), then calculates the difference.

Comment: @dclair: ok, please drop a line when your query completes :)

Comment: running it on a much smaller set to begin with to test it out